# replacing jcenter with mavenCentral and issue on com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5

Tags: android, jcenter

In an Android application,
I replaced **jcenter** with **mavenCentral** but the following item is not reachable now:

> implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'

The related Gradle is as following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        //jcenter()
        //mavenCentral()
        //google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        //jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Ther error is as follwoing:

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project F:\app\mApp

```
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build completed with 7 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/synnapps/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8m 3s
18 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 11 up-to-date
```

Is there any solution in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

It occurs when a library is not maintained and not upgraded to mavenCentral(). Go to the below link and follow the steps to update it in your project.  https://jitpack.io/#sayyam/carouselview

Comment: Yet I see the following error:Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.github.sayyam:carouselview:0.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/sayyam/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/sayyam/carouselview/0.1.5/carouselview-0.1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

Comment: com.github.sayyam:carouselview:0.1.5 remove this dependency from build.gradle file and use the latest one recommended by that link.

Comment: implementation 'com.github.sayyam:carouselview:master-SNAPSHOT' does not work too

Comment: implementation 'com.github.sayyam:carouselview:716e13e0af' it's wotking

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work yet => Could not resolve com.github.sayyam:carouselview:716e13e0af.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/sayyam/carouselview/716e13e0af/carouselview-716e13e0af.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/sayyam/carouselview/716e13e0af/carouselview-716e13e0af.pom'.

Comment: Share the GitHub link of your project if possible to look-up your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252001/discussion-between-abdullah-javed-and-androidplayer2).

Comment: I'm there to chat